# En C++ error de variable local sin inicializar

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vscode

Hola buenas tardes colegas, tengo una duda porque ahí me dice que se utilizó la variable local 'mes' sin inicializar, a que se refiere con eso, espero y me puedan ayudar

Saludos...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A pesar que las imagenes se ve de buena calidad, trata de agregar el código directamente en la pregunta, puesto así la gente podrá probarlo desde su editor de texto o IDE. Con respecto al error. El compilador se queja porque estás usando la variable `mes` en las condicionales sin darle un valor en especifico.

Answer (score 1):

El mes si no lo va a insertar el usuario querrás que lo obtenga el programa entonces debes incluir lo siguiente:

```
#include <time.h>
```

Y en tu código para declarar la variable mes hacer lo siguiente

```
time_t ahora;

//Obtiene la fecha actual del sistema
time(&ahora);

//Se convierte a una estructura tipo calendario para poder obtener todas las variables
struct tm *local = localtime(&ahora);

//Seleccionamos el mes de la estructura y tm_mon nos devuelve un número entre 0 y 11 por lo tanto le sumamos 1
int mes = local->tm_mon +1;
```

Este código lo obtuve de esta web, que está en inglés no sé si te sea de ayuda para otras cosas relacionadas con la fecha
https://www.techiedelight.com/print-current-date-and-time-in-c/

Espero sea de ayuda

Comment: Ohh. So tienes razón no me fijé, ahora mismo lo corrijo